# Struts 2 escape html doesn't work?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I have a Struts2 problem,

```jsp
<s:property escape="false" value="value" />
```

value is got from database, content html tags, Example:

```
TOTO<br/>Adresse:<br/>
```

when using Struts2 tag with escape false the result: `TOTO<br/>Adress:<br/>` and not the well formatted content, so anyone has an idea how to correct this? 
I try `escapeHhtml`, `escapeXML`, `escape`, always same problem... 
the result that I want is like:

```
TOTO
Adress:
```

Comment: My suggestion is better use some `CSS/HTML` in your `JSP`to format the output rather than taking help from the property tag

Comment: `escapeHtml="false"` should work. Are you sure that string comes in exact that format?

Comment: yes sure, and I try escapeHtml="false" but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code in the action

```
public String getValue(){
  return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(this.value);
}
```

then use with

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="value" />
```

Comment: Use `commons-lang3-3.1.jar`.