# how to make snippets or post body summary of blog posts in struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, ckeditor

I am making a blog in Struts2. When it was displayed blog post snippet or post body summary by

```
<s:property value="postSnip" escapeHtml=""/>
```

then (see in image) [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVTOj.png)  
 display gap and brack line. It not see as a signal line.
When I use the below code

```
<s:property value="postSnip" />
```

then see like this see image [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6GLU.png) it display in one line but also display HTML Tags

What can i do to solve this problem 
Please Help me

Comment: It's not clear what the question actually is, and you don't include the JSP code. If you want to display embedded HTML then you need to set `escapeHtml` to false or it will be escaped. You should also use a library to only allow "safe" HTML tags to avoid XSS.

Comment: how to make snippets or post body summary of blog posts in struts2

Comment: What's the *specific* question? I explained the `escapeHtml` property--what else do you need to know?

Comment: When is use **escapeHtml** (see In the first image) display gap and brack line. It not see as a signal line.
And when not use **escapeHtml** (see in the second image) then see in one line  but also display html Tags 
what is the solution

Comment: There are paragraph tags in the HTML--what do you expect? If you want to strip out HTML tags then strip them out.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with phpMyAdmin, though?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27800278/573032